# Trouble with Styling when using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using JQuery and AJAX to submit and process a from. When the user clicks the like button, the information, through AJAX is send to my like.php file. The like.php file processes the request and also creates the html for the unlike button. My Success function takes the html for the like button and replaces the like button with the new unlike button. Except, when I replace the like button with AJAX and JQuery, the structure of the unlike button is gone. What could I be doing wrong?

JQuery and AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".like-form").submit(function() {

        var dataString = $(this).serialize();
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "like.php",  
            data: dataString,
            success: function(html) {
                $this.replaceWith(html);
            }
        }); 

        return false; 

    });
});
```

Original Form:

```
<form class="like-form" method="post" action="">
    <div class="post-button">
        <button type="submit" type="submit" name="like"  
        class="like-button"/><p> Like </p></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Like.php:

```
// Code to process the form

//This replaces the original form on submit
<form class="like-form" method="post" action="">
    <div class="post-button">
        <button type="submit" type="submit" name="unlike"  
        class="like-button"/><p> Unlike </p></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Try enhancing the markup after the unlike button is added - `$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    try{
        FB.XFBML.parse(); 
    }catch(ex){}
});`

Comment: What do you mean by " ... the structure of the unlike button is gone ... " - you mean is not put in to the form?

Comment: It loses it's styling

Comment: @Ross - is this XFBML or just plain custom made HTML?

Comment: Are you using the `[name="like"]` attribute on the `button` element for styling purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is not proper HTML in both like and unlike:

```
<form class="like-form" method="post" action="">
    <div class="post-button">
        <button type="submit" name="Unlike" class="like-button"/>
<!-- two "type="
          closed with /> and an additional </button> at the end
-->
    </div>
</form>
```

Try to change the content with `$this.html(html);`